# File listing layout

Tags: html, css, html5, layout, cross-browser

I am designing a very basic file listing layout in HTML and CSS. Although its working but I would like to know if the following code could be improved upon so that its more good and follows the best practices. I am looking forward of supporting I.E 9+ too. Plus I would like to add a progress bar behind the `left-wing`. In other words I would like to show download progress behind the filename and time as a whole.

I am showing only the part I would like to review.  Note that some text is white, and is visible in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ffpx3twj/).

```css
#list-content
{
 margin:auto;
 margin-top: 5%;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 overflow-y: auto;
 position: absolute;
 width: 90%;
 height: calc(95% - 105px);
}
#file_list
{
 width: 100%;
}
#file_list li
{
 overflow: hidden;
 padding-top: 4px;
 padding-bottom: 4px;
}
.f_icon
{
 width: 10%;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
}
.f_icon img
{
 width: 32px;
 height: 32px;
 display: block;
}
.left_wing
{
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
}
.f_name
{
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 overflow: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.f_time
{
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-style: italic;
 color: cornflowerblue;
 padding-top: 2px;
}
.right_wing
{
 width: 40%;
 float: right;
 margin-top: 6px;
}
.f_size
{
 float: right;
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
.f_delete
{
 float: right;
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
 color: #B10002;
 margin-left: 15px;
 margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="list-content">
    <ul id="file_list">
        <li>
            <div class="f_icon"><img src="images/Docs-icon.png"></div>
            <div class="left_wing">
                <div class="f_name">File name Short and loooooooooooong.ext</div>
                <div class="f_time">Sep 08, 2016</div>
            </div>
            <div class="right_wing">
                <div class="f_delete"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-align-center" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <div class="f_size">34.50 MB</div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <div class="f_icon"><img src="images/Docs-icon.png"></div>
            <div class="left_wing">
                <div class="f_name">File name Short.ext</div>
                <div class="f_time">Sep 08, 2016</div>
            </div>
            <div class="right_wing">
                <div class="f_delete"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-align-center" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <div class="f_size">34.50 MB</div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `img`: `alt`

Each `ìmg` element needs an `alt` attribute. If the image is only decorative or redundant, use an empty value:

```html
<img src="images/Docs-icon.png" alt="">
```

#### `time`

You could use the `time` element for the dates:

```html
<time class="f_time" datetime="2016-09-08">Sep 08, 2016</time>
```

#### `abbr`

If you want, you could use `abbr` for "MB", and give the expansion in the `title` attribute:

```html
<div class="f_size">34.50 <abbr title="Megabyte">MB</abbr></div>
```

#### `span` instead of `i`

You [should not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22501699/1591669) use the `i` element for CSS icons. Use the meaningless `span` instead:

```html
<span class="fa fa-trash fa-align-center" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

#### Accessibility of delete function

Note that this icon will not be accessible (because the element has no content, and because of `aria-hidden` anyway). If it’s really a delete function (which the class name suggests), you should [provide alternate content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32854051/1591669) so that, for example, also users with screenreaders can delete files.

The most simple solution would be to use a `button` with an `img` that has an `alt` value like "Delete file xy":

```html
<button type="button"><img src="delete.png" alt="Delete file 'File name Short.ext'"></button>
```

#### Markup structure

It seems to me that you have a table, not a list. Then you should use the `table` element.

```html
<table>

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Size (in <abbr title="Megabyte">MB</abbr>)</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>File name Short and loooooooooooong.ext</td>
      <td><time datetime="2016-09-08">Sep 08, 2016</time></td>
      <td>34.50</td>
      <td><button type="button"><img src="delete.png" alt="Delete file 'File name Short and loooooooooooong.ext'"></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>File name Short.ext</td>
      <td><time datetime="2016-09-08">Sep 08, 2016</time></td>
      <td>34.50</td>
      <td><button type="button"><img src="delete.png" alt="Delete file 'File name Short.ext'"></button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: How can I have the delete css icon in the button instead of a full fledged png image?

Comment: @Ayan: You mean the icon displayed via CSS? I have not much experience with this, but can’t you display it in the `button` like you did it in `i`?

Comment: Done. Used span tags inside the button element. Is that a good markup?

Comment: @Ayan: As long as the button does not only consist of the CSS icon, this should be fine.